# why my console result is different between different Scope

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var permute = function(nums) {
    let list=[];
    generate=function(flag,result){
        if(flag===nums.length){
            list.push(result);//add something to list
            return ;
        } 
        //同位遍历
        for(let i =0;i<nums.length;i++){
            //skip重复
            if(result.includes(nums[i])) continue;
            result.push(nums[i]);
            generate(flag+1,result);
            //递归结束后弹出尾项
            result.pop();
        }
    }
    generate(0,[]);
    console.log(list);//but it's empty
};


permute([1,2,3,4]);
```

i run this code the console result is empty.i'm confused.when i console list in generate function it not empty.

Comment: list is **not empty** ... it has 24 empty arrays inside it

Comment: you mean result.pop() effect the console result?

Comment: yes,you are right,but why?

Comment: you have other issues - if you scatter some console logs within the code, you'll see that you will not get permutations at all ... you end up (before destroying it all) with the same permutation 24 times

Comment: when you pass in an array as a param it's passed by reference, based on what you're doing im guessing you want to make a copy of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out `result.pop` will work. This is because Javascript passes objects/arrays by reference and not value. You may want to read through the following [post](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) to understand it completely